# Remove and replace with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

With PostgreSQL I want to remove the image classes. The image classes has different ones. This is what I want to achieve of some sort:

```
<img src="#" class="one two three" alt="">
```

So that the result is:

```
<img src="#" class="" alt="">
```

So I can then do a UPDATE:

```
UPDATE posts SET content = 'class="new-class"' WHERE content = 'class=""'
```

I don't think the above is a good way to do it though.

Comment: While the question does not mention `regexp_replace()`, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) is most relevant. DO READ TO THE VERY END!

Answer (score 1):

```
update posts set content = replace(content, 'class="one two three"', 'class=""')
```

Comment: Sorry. But the `class="one two three"` could be in a another order for example `class="two one three"` or `class="new one image"`. How could that be achieved?

Comment: `update posts set content = replace(content, substring(content from '%#"class="%" #"%' for '#'), 'class="" ')`

Comment: @Ric.H, you should update your answer rather than post another comment ;)